# How to Zoom with Axes3D in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, zooming

I am generating a 3D plot using matplotlib.  I want to be able to zoom in on areas of interest.  Currently, I am able to pan but not zoom.  Looking at the mplot3d API, I learned about `can_pan():`

```
Return True if this axes supports the pan/zoom button functionality.

3D axes objects do not use the pan/zoom button.
```

and `can_zoom():`

```
Return True if this axes supports the zoom box button functionality.

3D axes objects do not use the zoom box button.
```

They both return False (I think can_pan returns False because the axes cannot pan AND zoom both but maybe I am reading the API wrong).

Is there a way to enable Zoom?  The API indicates it does not use the buttons.  Is there some way to enable zoom or set it so `can_pan()` and `can_zoom()` return `True`?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.genfromtxt('data_file.txt')

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.gca(projection='3d')
ax1.scatter(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2], c='r', marker='.')
plt.show()

ax1.can_zoom()
>>> False

ax1.can_pan()
>>> False
```

I am using Python 2.7 on an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit desktop version machine with matplotlib installed from the default repositories (I can look the versions up if that is pertinent).

Comment: Sorry for being snarky, but implement it ;).  The reason that `can_pan` and `can_zoom` return true is that this functionality does not currently exist.

Comment: @tcaswell, what do you mean by 'implement it'?  I could not find a setting to make `can_zoom()` or `can_pan()` return `True`.  Are you saying to program a method that does this?

Comment: I mean that the Axes3D class does not currently implement zoom via rectagle or to pan.  If you want to see these features in `Axes3D` then please implement them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually @tcaswell is correct that this functionality doesn't exist and so it returns false. Have you tried zoom-to-rectangle button on the plot window? That works perfectly. If you haven't yet, then refer to the matplotlib instructions on [Interactive Navigation](http://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html).
You can zoom in using two ways:

1. Clicking on pan/zoom button:

   > Press the right mouse button to zoom, dragging it to a new position. The x axis will be zoomed in proportionate to the rightward movement and zoomed out proportionate to the leftward movement.
2. Clicking on zoom-to-rectangle button:

   > Put your mouse somewhere over and axes and press the left mouse button. Drag the mouse while holding the button to a new location and release.

Comment: your comment led me to try using the right mouse button which does in fact zoom into the center of the plot.  This is good enough, thank you.  I previously tried using the pan/zoom button and the zoom-to-rectangle button but neither of these change the functionality of right or left mouse buttons.  Left rotates the 3D plot, right zooms in on the center.  Though it only zooms on the center, I could figure out a way to plot an box around the data with it offset from the center to shift the plot center.

Comment: If you want to really dig into 3d plots and don't mind adding another dependency to your program, you might wanna try mayavi instead of mpl.  Depends on your applications, but it's really powerful for 3d rendering.http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of zoom functionality, you can control the limit of the axis like

```py
RADIUS = 1.0  # Control this value.
ax1.set_xlim3d(-RADIUS / 2, RADIUS / 2)
ax1.set_zlim3d(-RADIUS / 2, RADIUS / 2)
ax1.set_ylim3d(-RADIUS / 2, RADIUS / 2)
```

and you see your data in closer view if you define RADIUS variable smaller. In this example you can zoom into and zoom out from the origin.
You can optionally choose other focus point although you need to calculate the appropriate limit to achieve the desired view. Hope this helps.

I'm not sure it works in python2 because I have no such environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in `matplotlib 3.3.4` you can in fact use the left (not right to perform zoom in) button in the mouse to draw a rectangle and after the zooming process unplug the right button. After this, the image will be zoomed out.

At least it's the case if for matplotlib use:

- `matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")`
- and for navigation toolbar use `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.NavigationToolbar2QT`.

Answer (score -1):

You could drag scroll wheel on mouse to zoom as well.